# How to manage z-index of navigation menu?

Tags: css, asp.net, z-index

I have ASP.NET application with navigation menu. I've created menu in code behind (C#) using HtmlGenericControl class ("ul" and "li" elements) and CSS. The CSS looks as following:

```
ul.navMenu {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100000;
}

ul.navMenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

ul.navMenu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

ul.navMenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    width: 100px;
    background: gainsboro;
    color: #010101;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.navMenu a:hover {
    background: #d91703;
    color: #ffffff;
}

ul.navMenu ul a {
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

ul.navMenu ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
}

ul.navMenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

ul.navMenu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

ul.navMenu li:hover ul ul {
    display: none;
}

ul.navMenu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

The issue is when I've set z-index to 100000 in order to keep it on top of all other elements, there are some windows that pop up and the menu is visible through them, which doesn't look nice. Please, take a look at the screen shot below where you can see white pop up window and menu line visible through it. The menu shouldn't be visible. It should be behind the window.

I'm not sure how to make it work.

[image: The screen shot]

Comment: Obviously the original z-index is too high. There really should be no reason to use a number that high. I suspect your original positioning context is flawed. However, without a small demo...it's hard to advise further.

Comment: I know that z-index is too high, but what value should be? Or there's another way to make it work...

Comment: Can't tell without a minimal demo...just reduce it until the problem no longer occurs. Or better yet...start at 0 and increase it until the problem goes away.

Comment: I've set z-index to 10000 and the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb... when planning your app design think in the different layers you are going to show. Think wich ones are going to show on top and wich ones are going to go below with others.

When you have this, just number your different layers from lower to higher, and keep in mind that layers without z-index have a z-index of 0.

If you want to be able to "insert" future layers in between of your current ones without having to recode your styles, you can number them in steps of 10.